# Including and excluding files with lftp mirror

Tags: bash, ftp, mirror, lftp

I have an ftp server and I would like to only download the files matching a certain pattern. These files are in a nested directory tree. This is what I did:

```
lftp -c 'open -e "mirror --parallel=8 -i .*abc\.zip . localmirrordir" http://site.ftp.com/'
```

This command downloads in the `localmirrordir` only the files matching the regex. But the issue is that this commandline does a full scan of the all the directories on the server every time it is run.

I was hoping to cut down on that time and my hope was to only inspect those paths on the server that match the regex. How can I do that ?

Additionally can you tell me why this command fails to fetch anything from the server at all:

```
lftp -c 'open -e "mirror --parallel=8 -x .* -x .*/ -i .*abc\.zip . localmirrordir" http://site.ftp.com/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly exclude directories you don't want to scan. When the first pattern is including, then lftp excludes all files first, but includes all directories. Last matching pattern provides the resolution about each file or directory. Directories are matched with a slash appended.

Comment: Can you give some code examples to explain your point better please ? That will make your answer very helpful for all.